# Run Haproxy 2.6.7 as service on CentOS 9

Tags: centos, systemd, haproxy

I want to run HAProxy 2.6.7 on my CentOS 9.

I have downloaded and compiled the project with `USE_SYSTEMD` flag enabled and installed the compiled file. Here are the commands I have used:

```
make TARGET=linux-glibc USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1  USE_OPENSSL=1 SSL_INC=/usr/include SSL_LIB=/usr/lib ADDLIB=-ldl ADDLIB=-lpthread USE_PROMEX=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1

make install 

mkdir -p /etc/haproxy 

mkdir -p /var/lib/haproxy  

touch /var/lib/haproxy/stats 

ln -s /usr/local/sbin/haproxy /usr/sbin/haproxy 

cp examples/haproxy.init /etc/init.d/haproxy 

chmod 755 /etc/init.d/haproxy 

systemctl daemon-reload 

systemctl start haproxy.service
```

The last instruction returns the following:

```
haproxy.service: Can't open PID file /run/haproxy.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
haproxy.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Failed to start SYSV:...
/run/systemd/generator.late/haproxy.service:20: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/haproxy.pid
```

Running

```
sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

with flags `-c` and `-d` don't show any problems. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one solution and one workaround (without really caring about the root cause):

here is the workaround: if we install HAProxy using yum first (currently it is of an older version 2.4) and then replace it with the compiled newer version, we wont face this problem.

For the RCA:
There should be a haproxy.service in systemd which currently does not exist... a template can be copied using

```
cp haproxy-2.6.7/admin/systemd/haproxy.service.in /etc/systemd/system/haproxy.service
```

(attention on renaming on target) and public read/write access be given to it:

```
chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/haproxy.service
```

then we just reload the systemctl daemon and start HAProxy service